# Xcode 6, Interface Builder size issues

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, autolayout

I am trying to put a textView inside of a tableViewCell and I am currently using autolayout. I do not understand why my textView is behaving badly (see screenshot below). I don't understand what to add in order to make the preview to display what I have in IB. Here is a screenshot...

[image]

Thank you for any help! I am new to Xcode 6. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: whats wrong with the preview? It looking fine for me. Can you elaborate your problem a bit?

Comment: Well, my question was already answered. The problem was in the preview, the textView goes beyond the screen @Clement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add constraints of `textView`, try to select the `textView`, in storyboard click the second button on bottom bar and add new constraints to its superview which is cell's contentView.

Comment: I got to the part with the constraints menu. After that, there are a bunch of options like with all different alignments. I don't see anything with setting it to the super view.

Comment: Uncheck the `constrain to margins`, and click on the dashed lines.

Comment: OMG, WOW! I spent so much time trying to figure that out! THANK YOU!! One question... Does this apply to all elements?

Comment: What is the all elements? Do you mean views or constraints?

Comment: Like on my next View Controller, there is no tableViewCell. I just put a textView in the main view. How do I add constraints for that? Is it the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the same thing, as long as it is a `UIView`, you can play with it.

Comment: Thank you! But when I do the same thing with unchecking "constrains to margins" and clicking on the 4 dashed lines, It disappears on the preview... Do you know why this happens? @

Comment: Possibly the constraints constant has a large value and textview is compressed to become invisible. Try to set its width constraint.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand... Also, btw this is on a new View Controller.

Comment: What I mean is if `trailing space to superview` or `leading space to superview` is too big, for instance,150, and if its superview's frame width is 320, then the textview's width would be 20.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Xcode 6 at the moment. I have reported it to them.

In the mean time you need to go to that little box down the bottom left of the Storyboard screen (`show document outline`) and select it. Select your view from in there and select your `UITextView`. Then resize or do what you need to that way.

***Warning***

Resizing the `UITableviewCell` by dragging it and not using the `Size Inspector` may resize your `textview` to `0` so you may have to repeat the process.

Comment: So you're saying that I should add constraints from using the document outline instead of clicking on elements on the storyboard?

Comment: Yep. That is what I have had to do whenever using UITextView at present. I do not know why it makes any difference but it does.

Comment: You can also use the Size Inspector to change things, it does not make any difference. Manually changing it by dragging it seems to make the errors occur. Let me know how you go

Comment: Well, I just did it with the elements within the storyboard and it works just fine. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Xcode 6 has really messed up a lot of seemingly simple things.